# Python - plotting density contour with two different dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, contour

I'm trying to make a hexbin with two different dimensional arrays.

```
mass_msun = subhalos['SubhaloMass'] * 1e10 / 0.704 # in units of M_sol     h^-1
lam = (subhalos['SubhaloSpin'])

plt.plot(mass_msun,lam)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylabel('$\lambda$')
plt.xlabel('Subhalo Mass [$M_\odot$]')
```

This gives me a nice plot as such.

[image]

What I want to do his create a 2d density contour from this plot. Something similar produced here: https://micropore.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/2d-density-plot-or-2d-histogram/

Problem is, I have different dimensional arrays. The `lam` array is of shape (121209,3) while the `mass_msun` is of shape (121209,).

Is there a way I can preserve the dimensional aspects of `lam` with the `mass_sun`? Or should I go about using a different command other histogram2d?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is still to reshape your data to fit the histogram parameter requirements:

```
n_col = lam.shape[1]
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(np.tile(mass_msum, n_col), lam.flatten(), your_range, your_bins)
```